# Oracle Apex - Calling Oracle SaaS RESTful API - how do I set URL parameter dynamically

Tags: oracle, api, rest, oracle-apex, saas

I'm trying to call out from APEX to an Oracle SaaS RESTful API.

I've got the GET working fine at /fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/suppliers
Now I want to use the PATCH which is /fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/suppliers/{supplierId}

I've tried giving the PATCH operation (database action of Update Row) a URL Pattern of /{supplierId} and then creating a Parameter of supplierId and whether I hardcode this value, or try and get it from a form item, it never works.
I tried setting the parameter to required, and I get an error
1 error has occurred
ORA-20999: Required Web Source IN parameter "supplierId" of type "URL Pattern" must have a value.

which suggests a value isnt getting to the parameter, even if I hardcode its value.

So I guess I'm not understanding something, can anyone shed any light?

Thanks a lot

[Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKLsY.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb8aA.png)

Comment: did you try to debug the apex session ?? perhaps there you can see more about the error.

Comment: Thanks @RobertoHernandez, I didn't know you could - how do you go about doing that?

Comment: you can do it using the properties. check this https://docs.oracle.com/html/E39147_04/debug_mode.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no debugging option in the Web Source Module configuration page. If for whatever reason the configuration does not work as expected (especially the discovery of the data profile), you can create the Interactive Report (IR) with the (incomplete) Web Source Module and run the IR with debug on. This way, you can find relevant information about how the API call is made and what possibly the problem is.

Comment: Thanks @RobertoHernandez, I'll give that a try.